# Basic Search Engine in MEAN Stack Website

Tags: javascript, solr, lucene, search-engine, mean-stack

I'm currently building a MEAN stack application for a school project. I'm pretty close to completion, but I can't figure out how to add search functionality.

It's a medical app, so I'm trying to create a search for ICD-10 codes. So all I want it to do it a basic search of symptom or code and display the result. It can't be the google custom search; it has to be something I can do locally through my document.

I've already looked into lucene and solr, but I feel like that is overkill when I'm only wanting to index a single document.

Can anyone help with this, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: How many ICD-10 codes in total? If the number is low, a front end angular filter should suffice. If it is more and you need a backend search, I recommend that each ICD-10 code is saved as a separate document. Will help with indexing. But will also help with writing a simple search function in Node that is exposed as a restful service using Express Route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to index each entry as a separate document. And Search Engine will give you niceties such as case-insensitive search, ranking when user enters words that match different parts of the entry, etc.

And, it is school project, what you will learn will be useful for real ones :-)